# How to load google maps libraries dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know [I can load libraries in google maps api v3 using `libraries` argument in URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries). Now I am in the situation where I cannot change the html markup, only javascript. Can google maps libraries be loaded dynamically using some javascript call, e.g. by calling some google api function? E.g. something like `google.load()`.

Comment: +1, good question. I would like to know the answer.

Comment: It appears that this is still not possible yet. There's an request on the issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3664

Answer (score -1):

Google maps documentation show a way to [asynchronously load the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)

Code from that page:

```
function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=API_KEY&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: thanks but this is a dirty trick based on changing the markup (btw you are missing the libraries= URL parameter). However I am more interested in a which loads the library after the google api has been already loaded - in the sense of `google.load()` ..

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is rather old, but I had the same problem recently. In my case I couldn't easily change the script-load-url but attach js-code afterwards. Double loading google-maps-js couldn't solve the problem as well beecause it is prohibited by google.

To use libraries I copied the code blocks I needed from the respective urls. For loading places it has looked like:

goto: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=de&libraries=places

and copy'paste the last block which looks like:

```
google.maps.__gjsload__('places', function(_){ ... })
```

include it in your script after loading the default api.

Remember: This is rather dirty but could solve problems for some of you. Cheers!