# Load additional Google Maps libraries dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a page where the Google Maps is being loaded with the Geometry library:

```html
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=xxx&language=en&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Is there a way, if I only have access to update the javascript on this page, to also load in the Places library?  i.e. I can't update or remove the HTML for the above script tag.

I know there's already a feature request to get this added to the API:

- https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3664

And this question has already been asked, without answer, 3 years ago:

- [How to load google maps libraries dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621756/how-to-load-google-maps-libraries-dynamically)

I'm hoping someone might have come up with a way to do this since then.

Comment: Seems this is one of the (many) useful features on which google failed to take any action since a couple of years...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is now available in the v=beta channel of the Google Maps JavaScript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dynamic-loading

If you have any issues using this API, please report them at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support#issue-tracker